# Preview and edit external website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a difficult one

I am trying to show an external website within my page (currently using an iframe)

The trick is I want to be able to edit the site

e.g. I really want to show a preview of another website that I can modify.

Not sure if there is any tools out there, was thinking of using a jquery request to create a page within my domain that I can edit?

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

If that would be possible from within the browser, that would be a bug.

The way you should do it, is creating some sort of a proxy on your own domain/server, and fetch the site through there. Then you're allowed to access the iframe and edit whatever you like.

Of course, the site won't run like it normally would, since it can't use its own cookies, AJAX calls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this js library could inspire you something!

[easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM)